# Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (>= 7.2.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'

Tags: azure, storage, .net-core, project.json

I try to use Windows Azure Storage inside my dotnet core system (my first dotnet core project).  I tried the [unit test for Azure Storage with dotnet core](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/tree/master/Test/AspNet/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Test) and it builds well.

But when I try to include the dependency to Azure Storage in my project.json, I receive this message:

> Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (>= 7.2.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.

Here is my full project.json file

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration":"1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables":"1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging":"1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final", "type": "build" },
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-rc3-309",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc3-309",
    "FluentValidation": "6.4.0-beta3",
    // "Serilog" : "2.0.0",
    // "Serilog.Extensions.Logging" : "1.0.0",
    // "Serilog.Sinks.Console" : "2.0.0"
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final", "type": "build" },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.0.0-*"
},
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "imports": [
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ]
    }
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "type": "platform"
            }
        },
        "imports": [
            // "dotnet5.6",
            "dnxcore50",
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ]
    }
},
"buildOptions": {
    "define": [ "NETCORE"], 
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
},
"runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
},
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet bundle" ],
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [
        "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
},

"tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "Wod6000"
}
```

}

Do you have an idea on what is wrong?

Comment: did u try after uncommenting `dotnet5.6 ` in `frameworks : imports` section?

Comment: @Venky at first, dotnet5.6 was not commented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our package is named `WindowsAzure.Storage`. Can you try that instead?

Comment: Omg, i had the exact same error just with another package, i think that is one of the worst error messages ever for misspelling a package name :D